# Find position of a particular registry - ranking / asp classic / mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database containing several 
records. I need to know how to identify in which position the 
record was recently placed, make a ranking system and a 
position according to the score.

Example, I have the following records in the database

```
user-01 / 100 points
user-02 / 88 points 
user-03 / 55 points 
user-04 / 11 points 
user-05 / 30 points
```

With this I would like to know in which place is user-03, here it's the third, what should I do for the system to show me this placement?

Thanks!

Comment: I edited your question, is this what you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a row number column in your result set. To initialise the variable, `JOIN` to a pseudo-table that just sets your variable to 0 - otherwise you'd have to `SET` it beforehand - requiring an extra statement.

To demonstrate:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE scores (user VARCHAR(10), score INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO scores 
    -> VALUES ('user1', 10), 
    -> ('user2', 20), 
    -> ('user3', 30);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT user, score, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
    -> FROM scores 
    -> JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) rownum 
    -> ORDER BY score DESC;
+-------+-------+------+
| user  | score | rank |
+-------+-------+------+
| user3 |    30 |    1 |
| user2 |    20 |    2 |
| user1 |    10 |    3 |
+-------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but was having this "user-03" kind of row repeating multiple times. And also I was using two tables.

Structure of tables:

Score Table[score float,uid int,timestamp datetime]
User Table[username varchar(500), id int, etc...]

The criteria for ranking was to list users based on maximum scores.  So I have modified the query using **group by** and **JOIN** on the sql query as given below.

Ranking System.

```
SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank 
FROM (
       select  MAX(s.score) as score,u.username as username 
       from scorelog s join userdb u on s.uid=u.id 
       group by s.uid 
       order by MAX(s.score) desc
      ) user_rank, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
```

To Identify individual row's position and it's rank on the db use the below query.
The

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT *, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank 
       FROM (
             select  MAX(s.score) as score,
                     u.username as username,
                     s.uid as uid,s.
                     timestamp as timestamp 
             from scorelog s join userdb u on s.uid=u.id 
             group by s.uid order by MAX(s.score) desc
             ) user_rank, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
       )t where username = 'johndoe'
```

Also refer the below resources from stackoverflow which give similar solution.

[querying for user's ranking in one-to-many tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111290/querying-for-users-ranking-in-one-to-many-tables)

[SQL ranking solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043340/sql-ranking-solution)

[PHP MYSQL query result "RANKING"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567871/php-mysql-query-result-ranking)